# 400 Error for PowerForm on Demo

Tags: docusignapi

I am on the Demo platform trying to create a PowerForm.  When I press "Create PowerForm" on a template I get the modal for creating the powerform. But when I press the Create button nothing happens.

I get the following error in the console though:

```
https://appdemo.docusign.com/api/accounts/{{UUID}}/powerforms 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

I don't think this is a local error, as Docusign Live support tried to suggest.

Also the [documentation for PowerForms](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-create-a-powerform) shows a dropdown under the Use button. But my Use button is just a button, not a dropdown.

Comment: Are you using the DocuSign website for this or the API? If you're using the API, can you attach your request body?

Comment: I was using the website not the api

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved. PowerForms should work just fine on Demo.